# Split associative array based on keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
array (
    [customer_name] =>{customer1,customer2}
    [phone] => {123456,123456}
    [email] => {test@example.com,test2@example.com}
    [project] =>  {"Project A","Project B"}
    [property] => {A1,A2}
    [amount] =>  {100.00,2000.00}
  )
```

I want to split the array based on keys and assign to different variables. For example

```
$customer_name=array(customer1,customer2)
$phone=array(123456,123456)
// and so on
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As php.net says you can try with extract -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use foreach to do that and reassign variables inside the loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $values) {
    $values = str_replace(array('{', '}'), '', $values);
    ${$key} = explode(',', $values);
}
```